# How to start a SYSTEM thread from an administrative user

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++

How to create an application runs under `"SYSTEM"` user ?

I have a program running under the user `"My_User"` having administrator privilege. Is it possible to start a thread that is running under the program `"SYSTEM"` or the thread that has the privileges of SYSTEM thread ?

Is it possible to start a thread which is running under `"My_User"` from an application under `"SYSTEM"` ?

Comment: Have you ever tried to read Win32 documentation about that?

Comment: I've yet to see a case where this made sense. Running a service as `SYSTEM` usually makes more sense.

Comment: we are searching on that, could u please help us,